# Is possible override the version of a dependency in child POM?

Tags: java, maven

I'm working with Maven to management the dependencies of my projects. I have my parent POM and I'm using Dependency Management to avoid write the common dependencies in each project.

Now, I need change the version of one dependency in my child POM.

I have this of my parent POM

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencyManagement>
```

My child POM has a reference to the parent POM

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.myproject</groupId>
    <artifactId>root-parent-pom</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0.22</version>
    <relativePath>../parent/pom.xml</relativePath>
 </parent>
```

And in this child POM I want to override the version of the same dependency that I wrote in the parent POM, something like this.

```
<dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>
</dependency>
```

I did that, but when I generate my project, in this case is a WAR, the final version of the dependency that is included in my project is the version that is described on the parent POM.

Is possible override the version in child POM?

Comment: Side note: you never accepted any answer to [your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1630664/edla-sk8?tab=questions) yet. If an answer suited your need, you should [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/186921).

Comment: Why would you need to do this? Why can't you define the version in a parent pom to avoid any possible confusions?

Comment: @sp00m sorry, I'm very new using stackoverflow, and I didn't know that I have to accept answers from my questions, thanks for the tip, I will review all my questions and accept the best answer.

Comment: @user1745356 I need to to that because the parent POM is shared in 2 different projects, and is very complicated change the version on the parent POM because I don't know if this will come to an possible issue.

Comment: @edla.sk8 try to define this dependency in a war project

Comment: @user1745356 your solution works perfectly, thanks! Can you post that solution as an answer to accept it as an answer please? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe. If you specify a distinct version, then this version will override the one in the `dependencyManagement` element.

But only for this single POM. It doesn't magically distribute to the next POM in the reactor build *unless* the next POM has this POM as parent. So if you have this setup:

```
parent
- mod1
- mod2
- war
```

and you put this into `mod1`, then the `war` won't notice since `war` uses `parent` as parent POM. The dependency `mod1` says "please use `2.6`" but that's the same as any other pom which uses `2.1` - there is no reason to prefer that over the other. That's the power of `dependencyManagement`: You get a single place where you can control the versions of all transitive dependencies.

Try `mvn help:effective-pom` to see what Maven will use in each part of your build.

To make the WAR pick up the overwritten version, you need to specify it in the parent POM of the WAR or in the WAR's POM itself.

The usual solution is to have a parent POM for all projects which sets the default versions (2.1). Then you have a parent POM per project which inherits from the global parent POM. Here you can set the version to 2.6. Since all modules of the project inherit from it, the per-project parent POM takes precedence.

Comment: Specifying in the WAR's POM works fine. That was a solution given by by @user1745356. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define that dependency in a war project.