# The attribute "alternate" is undefined for the annotation type SerializedName

Tags: java, json, gson

I am using com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName with elements "value" and "alternate" as mentioned in gson docs `@SerializedName(value= "Active", alternate = {"Active","Pending"})`, but the compiler says error:
"The attribute alternate is undefined for the annotation type SerializedName".

Comment: What version of Gson are you using, I am using this syntax successfully, as mentioned in this SO:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25707728/multiple-gson-serializedname-per-field
this was introduced in Gson 2.4

Comment: Yeah, I tried adding 2.8.0 version in pom.xml, but I wonder why its not overriding parent's pom version of 2.2.0, even after cleaning and rebuilding the app?

Comment: Is there any reason why the parent pom is on such an old version?

Comment: maybe this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25019211/is-possible-override-the-version-of-a-dependency-in-child-pom SO might help?

Comment: I will follow up the link, thanks Bill. let me upvote you.

Answer (score 1):

The `alternate` version of the `@SerializedName` annotation was added in Gson version 2.4, so will not work in earlier versions.
It seems that occasionally the parent pom may prevent overriding the version (see above discussion).